# APP MAKER not available for all users of my organization

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm a teacher at a secondary school in Italy. We have activated GSUITE since two years ago, we have also already activated the APP Maker service. I've prepared some lessons form my students. APP Maker works fine with the administrator user and another teacher user. It doesn't work with the users I've  created for my students connected to the same domain but a different organization. APP Maker service is active for all organization.

When we try to follow a APP Maker tutorial as student account we receive a massege like this: "Sorry, you don't have access to this service [...]".

Somebody has already solved this problem?

Thank's in advance for your help.

Comment: This seems more like a GSuite support question https://gsuite.google.com/support/

Comment: This may also be useful ... https://developers.google.com/appmaker/getting-started/faq#am_access  it seems to say that "G Suite Education" does indeed have availability of App Maker.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure appmaker is enabled for student organization. Yes, try to raise gsuit support. They are very responsive.